# can't change pipeline state PLAYING to PAUSE

Tags: gstreamer

I simply constructed the pipelines as follows.

gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=~/Desktop/gstremer/basic_tutorial/waterfall-158229.mp4 ! tee name=t ! queue ! filesink location=~/Desktop/gstremer/basic_tutorial/ll.mp4 t. ! queue ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! autovideosink

This pipeline works, but there is a problem when changing the pipeline state from playing state to puase state.

I checked and found that the filesink does not seem to be paused, preveinting the pipeline from transitioning to the pause state.

I also made an interesting discovery: when i set the async property of the filesink element to false, the pipeline transitions to the paused state correctly.

Question

1. what exactly does the async property of the filesink element do?
2. When I set the async property to false, the pipeline transitions to the paused state correctly. Why does this happen?

Thanks.

changed pipeline state Playing to Paused correctly.